# Установить, присутствует ли элемент в массиве (С#)

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть переменная, содержащая имя, например:

```
string name = "Коля";
```

и массив, содержащий имена, например:

```
string[] array = { "Коля", "Федя", "Фрося", "Мотя" };
```

Как проверить, есть ли имя, указанное в переменной, в массиве?

Comment: я не специалист по C#, но думаю нужен какой то цикл, в котором вы будете сравнивать переменную name c каждым элементом массива.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Можно сделать несколькими различными способами, к примеру:

```
string name = "Коля";
string[] array = { "Коля", "Федя", "Фрося", "Мотя" };

// Способ #1
foreach (string str in array)
{
    if (str == name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Слово '{0}' содержится в массиве", name));
        // to do something...
    }
}

// Способ #2
if (array.Any(str => str == name))
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Слово '{0}' содержится в массиве", name));
    // to do something...
}

// Способ #3
if (array.Contains(name))
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Слово '{0}' содержится в массиве", name));
    // to do something...
}
```

Список полезных ссылок на MSDN для изучения:

1. [foreach, in (Справочник по C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx)
2. [Enumerable.Any - метод](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. [String.Contains - метод](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)
4. [Intersect - метод](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: может стоит добавить про [`Intersect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx) в список полезного для изучения

Answer (score 9):

Можно воспользоваться [классом `HashSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) и [методом `Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb356440(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string name = "Коля";
string[] array = { "Коля", "Федя", "Фрося", "Мотя" };

var hash = new HashSet<string>(array);

if (hash.Contains(name))
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Слово '" + name + "' содержится в массиве"));
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Через LINQ

```
bool result = array.Any(n => n == name);
```

Answer (score 6):

Выяснить, содержит ли массив искомый элемент, или нет, можно с помощью функций
[`Array.Exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yw84x8be(v=vs.110).aspx) или [`Array.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
contains = Array.IndexOf(array, name) != -1;
```

или

```
contains = Array.Exists(array, v => v == name);
```

Answer (score 2):

Через `List<>` (net 2.0)

```
List<string> lst= new List<string>(array);
bool result = (lst.IndexOf(name) >=0);
```

можно упростить

```
((IList<string>)array).IndexOf(name);
```

Comment: Массив - это уже список. Зачем обертка-то?

Comment: На прямую в array нету свойства IndexOf. Что б было доступно IndexOf нужно через Array или через `List<>`

Comment: Если скастить массив к [`IList<string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx) - появится.

Comment: Хороший вариант.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Linq;

string name = "Коля";
string[] array = { "Коля", "Федя", "Фрося", "Мотя" };
if (array .Contains(name))
{
    Action();
}
```

Используйте Linq, там есть метод Contains, и как бы получите желаемое + код выглядит более лаконичным.
Если использовать без Linq Conatins, то возможна ошибка(у меня так было + он смотрит на наличие в строке заданной подстроки

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. в частности, объясните, пожалуйста, чем ваше предложение отличается от [способа номер три из соседнего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/557954/178576).