# Сравнение двух коллекций разных типов

Tags: c#, linq

Есть список companyList построенный на основании выполнения запроса, содержит имена компаний, и есть directoryList построенный на DirectoryInfo. Как в linq дописать условие на соответствие имен каталогов, именам в списке companyList.

```
List<string> companyList = new List<string>();
        using (SqlCommand addToCompanyList = new SqlCommand("SELECT [PROV_LATNAME]  FROM [dbfTo1c].[dbo].[FileFormat]"))
        {
            addToCompanyList.Connection = new SqlConnection(Connection.dbfTo1c_ConectionString);          
            addToCompanyList.Connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = addToCompanyList.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())                
                companyList.Add(Convert.ToString(reader["PROV_LATNAME"]));
            //listBox1.DataSource = companyList;                        
            reader.Close();              
            addToCompanyList.Connection.Close();                
        }

        DirectoryInfo[] directoryList = new DirectoryInfo(path)
           .EnumerateDirectories()
           .Where(dirInfo => Regex.IsMatch(dirInfo.Name, searchP))
           .ToArray();
```

Comment: да так же, добавить еще один `Where`

Comment: Должно быть строгое совпадение с именами папок, или название компании, должно входить в название папки, во втором случае, что делать  если результатов поиска несколько?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Установить, присутствует ли элемент в массиве (С#)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/557945/%d0%a3%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%83%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%a1)

Comment: в описанном вами случае можно воспользоваться методом [`Intersect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188055(v=sql.120).aspx) т.е. что то типа `var result =  first.Select(x=>x.Name).Intersect(second.Select(x=>x.Name))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем как-то так)))

```
DirectoryInfo[] directoryList = { };
        List<DirectoryInfo> di = new DirectoryInfo(path).EnumerateDirectories().ToList<DirectoryInfo>();
        directoryList = di.FindAll(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.Name.Replace("-" , "_") , searchP) && companyList.Exists(s => s == x.Name)).ToArray();
```