# Программа, которая ищет названия файлов и вписывает их в текстовый файл

Tags: c#, list

```
for (int i = 0; i < filesnames.Count; i++)
{
   if (lines[i] != ("fallback-archive=" + filesnames[i]))
   {
      File.AppendAllText(pathow, ("fallback-archive=" + filesnames[i]));
   }
}
```

Есть список с названиями файлов и со строками из текстового файла.
Нужно, чтобы программа определяла, есть ли такие названия файлов в текстовом документе, если нет, то нужно вписать. В итоге получается, что программа вписывает в файл вместо нужных названий все, даже не построчно, а в одну строку.
По какой причине выводится все, а не то, что нужно?

Comment: Программа написана все делает, но почему-то не выводит, что нужно, а все подряд (хотя условие есть)

Comment: Будет полезно для вашего случая: [Установить, присутствует ли элемент в массиве С#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/557954/189339)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

принципиальные ошибки:

1. ваш код сравнивает на неравенство. поэтому в файл попадают имена файлов НЕ СОВПАДАЮЩИЕ с lines.
2. ваш код сравнивает имя i-ое файла с i-ой строкой. чтобы определить "есть ли такое название". нужно сравнить со всеми lines, а не только с lines[i]
3. AppendAllText добавляет только то, что вы сказали. этот метод не добавляет перевод строки по своей инициативе. поэтому добавьте "\r\n" в ваш код

ну и конечно, для задач поиска текста лучше воспользоваться [regexp-выражениями](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx).

upd: и еще приведенная вами постановка логически не полна: как программа должна реагировать на частичное совпадение? Например, если lines:

```
text for searach
```

а искомые имена filesnames:

```
text for
for search
```

Comment: лучше добавлять `Environment.NewLine`, а не \r\n

Comment: абсолютно согласен

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var scanDir = @"C:\Windows";
        var fileType = "*.exe";
        var logfile = @"D:\logdir.txt";

        var namesForSave = (from fileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(scanDir, fileType)
                            from line in GetNamesFromTxt(logfile).DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where fileName != line
                            select fileName).ToList();

        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(logfile))
        {
            foreach (var name in namesForSave)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(name);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetNamesFromTxt(string logfile)
    {
        if (File.Exists(logfile))
        {
            return File.ReadAllLines(logfile);
        }
        else
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }
    }
}
```